# Add a Submenu from Another Submenu in a Custom Theme

Tags: menus, themes, sub-menu, add-submenu-page

Good day everyone! I would like some help from you since I'm just a beginner in WordPress. I would like to add a submenu under another submenu like this:

- International

  - China Independent

    - Group Tours
    - DPRK Add-ons
    - Classic Chin
    - YPT Exclusive
    - Ticket Services'

I don't have a problem adding them under 'China Independent' when I go to 'Appearance>Menu', however, they don't show up[maybe because it is indeed a custom theme] and I want them to be seen as drop down list on hover since China Independent is another different page. How can I achieve this?

You can see this image:
 [image]

Or the link: http://www.developerspace.co.vu/

All your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are adding the menu levels as separate menus:

- A "Primary menu" containing the items: "HOME", "DPRK TOURS", "INTERNATIONAL", ... etc.
- A "Secondary menu" containing the items: "INTERNATIONAL GROUP TOURS", "VOLUNTEER PROGRAMS", ... etc.

However, most themes support at most *two* such menu-levels, and some even support only *one*.  So, if you are looking to set up a "Tertiary menu" (with items "Group Tours", "DPRK Add-Ons", ... etc.), I doubt that your theme natively supports this!

Instead, you should consider using just a *single* ("Primary") menu, containing a multi-level structure (with even three or more levels).  The WordPress built-in menu-editor allows you to edit this multi-level menu using a [simple drag-and-drop interface](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide#Creating_Multi-level_Menus).